# How to use Ruby to download multiple files from a webpage?

Tags: ruby

I want to download all of the excel files (.xls) linked on [this](http://www.whitehouse.gov/omb/budget/historicals) page.

Is there a Ruby gem which can do this for me? If not, how do I go about writing a Ruby script which will download each of the excel files into a designated folder?

Comment: There isn't a Ruby gem that will automatically do that. You'll have to tell it which file to download at a minimum, but, because you are a programmer, and Ruby is a programming language, you should be able to do that, right? I'd recommend you look into either Ruby's own [OpenURI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/index.html), or the [Curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb) gem. The file retrieved will be binary, so you'll want to save it using the "wb" mode for `File.open`.

Comment: Thank you I will check out both of these, that's exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for!

Answer (score 4):

> Spreadsheets
>
> To download all Historical Tables in XLS format as a single ZIP file,
>   click here (788 KB)

As stated right on their web page.  Please do read the page you are on to save some programming, as everyone knows the best programmers are especially lazy!

Comment: Dang it, fail on my part!

Comment: Anyway, the thing I want to try do is to write a program that will extract the information. Those excel files on that website are just an EXAMPLE OF WHAT I AM TRYING TO LEARN TO ACCOMPLISH. Anyway, I will definitely remember to pick a better example next time. And I will check out OpenURI and the Curb gem.

Comment: Look forward to some good questions from you @MattLemmon

Comment: Thank you, I will spend extra time quadruple-checking them before submission. :)